# Shared Mac not showing in Another Mac Sidebar Locations

Tags: macos, file-sharing

I am using iMac running macOS Big Sur and MacBook Air running Mojave.

Both of them have File sharing and screen sharing on.

While my iMac shows the MacBook Air automatically in sidebar under locations when they are on the same network but my MacBook Air doesn't show the iMac under the locations Sidebar.

If I go to network it shows the iMac and I can connect but I want it to automatically show up in the sidebar locations.

P.S. Finder preferences on both systems have the connected servers, bonjour etc. checked.

Comment: This happens to me as well, never figured it out but if you click on "Network" in the sidebar the "missing" mac will show up there.

Comment: Yes it shows there but I want it to appear automatically under locations, any way to do so? Been breaking my head since hours....On iMac MacBook Air is detected automatically in sidebar under locations but MacBook Air for some reason is not detecting the iMac under locations

Comment: Yah, it is strange and annoying, but I never discovered a fix. Perhaps someone else here has...